# How to Control Content Delivery Setting in Apex Program?

Tags: apex

I want to control Content Delivery Option in Programmatic way. so does salesforce provides any api to access this functionality.
Also We can control it mannualy by,
Admin | Setup | customize | Content Delivery
but want to know in programmatic way

Comment: I have a similar problem - couldn't add or delete Content Delivery entity via Apex.
And sObject doesn't exists...

Answer (score 7):

As of [winter 15 this is now possible](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HMq4AAG):

```
ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
cd.name = 'test';
cd.ContentVersionId = '12312132abad';
cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = false;
cd.PreferencesAllowPDFDownload = false;
cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
insert cd;

cd = [SELECT DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ID = :cd.Id];
System.debug(cd.DistributionPublicUrl);
```

You can basically do anything you can do in the native UI.  Add password, set expiration, allow download, etc.  I can't find any official documentation yet, but you can explore the properties using the workbench.  Just make sure your API version is set to 32.

[image: screenshot ContentDistribution Object in workbench]

Comment: Don't forget to add
`cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;`
to prevent the owner from getting an email the first time someone views the document.

Comment: Just tried it from my end, password field is not writable,Field is not writeable: ContentDistribution.Password

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do this via Apex.  I searched long and hard for this a while back when a customer had some automation requirements, but I couldn't find an sobject that contains the content delivery information.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but perhaps this could help.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspacedoc.htm